# System of congruences with polynomials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

How do I go about solving exercises such as this one:

Find all polynomials $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ that satisfy

$$f(x) \equiv 1 \space \space \mathrm{mod} \space \space x^2 + 1$$
$$f(x) \equiv x \space \space \mathrm{mod} \space \space x^3 + 2x + 2$$

in $\mathbb{Z}_3.$

I know about the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but only how to apply it to system of congruences where there are no polynomials involved.

I realise that $f_1(x) \equiv f_2(x) \space \space \mathrm{mod} \space  g(x)$ means that $f_1(x) - f_2(x)$ is divisible by $g(x)$, but that's about as far as I've come with this problem.

Also, if anyone has any advice as to where I can read about modular arithmetic involving polynomials, I'd be happy to hear about it, because the literature I have doesn't say much about it at all, and I would like to learn.

Comment: You can perform the extended Euclidean Algorithm on polynomials.

Comment: Do you mean I should treat is as I would a system without polynomials and apply the CRT? I don't know how to do that, since normally I would try to find $x_i : x_i N_i \equiv 1 \space \space \mathrm{mod} \space n_i$  which in this case would be something like $x_i (x^2 + 1) \equiv 1 \space \space \mathrm{mod} \space (x^2 + 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the constructive proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Here is a roadmap:

- Let $p(x)=x^2+1$ and $q(x)=x^3+2x+2$.
- Use the extended Euclidean Algorithm in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ to find polynomials $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ such that $u(x)p(x)+v(x)q(x)=1$.
- Set $f(x)=(1)v(x)q(x)+(x) u(x)p(x)$ mod $3$.

Comment: For the second step, which is boring, you may want to ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialExtendedGCD%5Bx%5E2%2B1%2C+x3%2B2x%2B2%5D).

Comment: I tried following your pointers. I reach the result $1 = (x+1)(x^3+2x+2) + (2x^2+2x+2)(x^2+1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, which then should give me the answer $(x+1)(x^3+2x+2) + x(2x^2 + 2x + 2)(x^2+1)$, however, apparently the answer should be $2x^3+2x+1+(x^2+1)(x^3+2x+2)g(x)$... Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @vincefontaine I haven't checked, but you may want to see if the answers are indeed the same I.e differ only in a suitable choice of $g(x)$ in $\mathbb Z_3[x]$.